# android scrollbar length with different item sizes

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

I have a listview with a comments. Comments has different length(from 1 line to 20, for example). 
And while I'm scrolling this listview, standard scrollbar increases and decreases, depending of what the comment I'm scrolling in this moment.
Why is it happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need. Just set it `false`

[setSmoothScrollbarEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setSmoothScrollbarEnabled%28boolean%29)

Comment: Thanks, this will help for a while. But not smooth scrollbar is not so cool. It's lagging, while I'm scrolling. I think this is not good, when the scrollbar resizing, but in a market, for example, in a comments, it is present.

Answer (score 7):

I found this online on why this happens. Not sure why Google decided make lists height-agnostic.

> If the `ListView` contains items with variable heights, the `ListView` has no way of knowing the full height of all the items it contains so the height of the thumb is calculated based on the number of items in the view and the number of items currently visible. The number of items currently visible varies, so the thumb height varies too.
>
> On iOS the equivalent component (`UITableView`) requests the height of all items from the `UITableViewDataSource` before the view is shown so the overall thumb size can be known and kept consistent.
>
> > **Max Howell,** Last.fm developer
> > [*Why does the scroll bar change its length during scrolling?*](http://www.quora.com/Android-OS/Why-does-the-scroll-bar-change-its-length-during-scrolling)

Comment: To be able to know the height of the listview, you should create every item and do the sum of their height. But this is not what happen, the items are create when needed (on screen only) so there is no way to get the height. This isn't perfect but this is the most efficient way to work. (especially with a list of thousands of items).